# Change the class of an already initialized variable

Tags: c#

For testing purposes I want to be able to change which class is bound to the variable `sensor`. Normally the program would use data measured by a sensor through the `Sensor` class. However, if no sensor is connected, I can simulate its behavior using the `SensorSimulator` class.

What I currently do is comment out the class which I do not want to use. How can I make it work such that with the click of a button in the GUI I can switch between the `Sensor` and `SensorSimulator` classes? Or is there alternative way to do this?

## Code

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO_question
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //private Sensor sensor;
        private SensorSimulator sensor;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //sensor = new Sensor();
            sensor = new SensorSimulator();

            var data = sensor.getData();
            sensor.stopMeasuing();
        }
    }

    class Sensor
    {
        public virtual int getData()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public void stopMeasuing() { }
    }

    class SensorSimulator : Sensor
    {
        public override int getData()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good use case of dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface to define the classes.

```
public interface ISensor
{

    int GetData();

    void StopProcessing();
}


public class Sensor : ISensor
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void StopProcessing()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SensorSimulator : ISensor
{
    public int GetData()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public void StopProcessing()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
        ISensor sensor;
        sensor = new Sensor();

        sensor = new SensorSimulator();
```

Comment: Is `SensorSimulator` still able to inherit methods from `Sensor` in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can intherit from Sensor directly, but GetData must be virtual to  enable you to override it.

Answer (score 3):

Create interface ISensor and let both Sensor and SensorSimulator implement it. Thats it.

EXTENDEND ANSWER:

```
public interface ISensor
{
    SensorData GetData();
}

public class SensorData
{
}

public class Sensor : ISensor
{
    public SensorData GetData()
    {

        return new SensorData();
    }
}

public class SensorSimulator : ISensor
{
    public SensorData GetData()
    {
        return new SensorData();
    }
}

public class SensorHost
{
    public ISensor Sensor { get; set; }

    public void Measure()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sensor.GetData());
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SensorHost host = new SensorHost();
        host.Sensor = new Sensor();
        // measures by real sensor
        host.Measure();

        host.Sensor = new SensorSimulator();
        // measures by sensor simulator
        host.Measure();

    }
}
```

Here you can see the idea. Program will create SensorHost ~ the code you have in Form1. This host keeps the property Sensor of type ISensor. So you can set it to the whatever that implements this interface. First call of Measure() will use the real Sensor. The second call will be called on SensorSimulator. It is called polymorphism.

Comment: just to be sure -> variable will be of type ISensor and that way you can switch the implementation anytime

Comment: They already implement the same base type. How does an interface change anything?

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec, I will edit the answer... OOP basics BTW.

Comment: @Roald I would suggest having a look into Dependency Injection. The button behaviour you describe can be achieved changing the DI configuration (when working with interface `ISensor` use class `SensorSimulator`) that way all your application would behave in a consistent manner.

Comment: As a bonus... Implementing interfaces in your code make it quite easy to add unit tests to your code.

Comment: @bradbury9 and Divisadero thanks for the advise and the prompt responses. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @RufusL I am not sure that code was there when I wrote the answer. And basically, interface is way to go in general.

Comment: Yeah, it was part of the original question. But I agree, interfaces are far more flexible. Although if `SensorSimulator` *is a* `Sensor`, then inheritance may be appropriate.

Comment: @RufusL I guess you will end up with intefrace so or so due to access modifiers. Very often you want the interface to be public, but implementation would be internal. Common sight is something like SensorSimulator : Sensor, ISensor

Answer (score 2):

Although creating a common interface is usually preferable, you don't *have* to do anything to your existing code, you can just switch the type at runtime, as long as you declare `sensor` as the base class type `Sensor` and don't expect to use any `SensorSimulator`-specific methods:

```
private Sensor sensor;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sensor = new Sensor();           
    var data = sensor.getData();
    sensor.stopMeasuing();
}    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Detect the type of `sensor` and switch it
    if (sensor is SensorSimulator) sensor = new Sensor();
    else sensor = new SensorSimulator();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I use `SensorSimulator` specific methods.

Comment: Oh, ok. So currently you do a little more than just comment out the class which you do not want to use, then...

Comment: Turns out I did not use the `Sensor` class in a while and in the mean time I added a `SensorSimulator` specific method.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Then this wouldn't work if you needed to call that method. I have another idea that also would work that I'll post shortly.